# Google Maps not showing due to Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using Google Maps in my app

I am doing testings now, the problem is that maps always show as grey screen (No maps showing)

I tried different devices with different androids still the same

I know that Google Play Services has to be installed.

I added this code to make sure user get notified if Google Play Services is not installed but no notification what so ever gets displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Then we're good to go!
    }
    isGpsEnabled(getApplicationContext());
}

public static boolean isGpsEnabled(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        String providers = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(providers)) {
            return false;
        }
        return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } else {
        final int locationMode;
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        switch (locationMode) {

            case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY:
            case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY:
                return true;
            case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING:
            case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF:
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            showErrorDialog(status);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void showErrorDialog(int code) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this,
            REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
}
static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 1001;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This is the code to setup the maps

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded(String result) {
  //  mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) .getMap();

    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap(result);


            FocusMap();
            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Intent addNew = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ItemDetail.class);
                    String Header = marker.getTitle();
                    int Pos = Header.indexOf(":");
                    String siKey = Header.substring(0, Pos);
                    addNew.putExtra("iKey", siKey);
                    startActivity(addNew);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

and this is from gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

I even tried to download Google Play Services directly from the play store but could not find it in the play store !! I found Google Play Games and other apps but not Google Play Services.

I feel I am missing something but not sure what.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: First, please post your map code.  Also, go to Application Manager and look at the version of Google Play Services, and make sure it's above the version that you compile with (I suspect it's good).

Comment: Add a log entry where you have the comment `Then we're good to go!` and see if gets logged.

Comment: yes it does, i added a break point there, i got the cursor in there

Comment: Ok, well then it's not a problem with Google Play Services.  Any errors in the logs?

Comment: the logcat is too big and keep adding new lines too fast, not sure how to check it

Comment: Did you do all this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key